# How to detect secchi disk marker in the image?

Tags: image-processing, feature-detection

What would be lightweight and reliable method to detect [secchi disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secchi_disk) in the image?

Comment: Maybe start with a corner detector, then do some local analysis to confirm the geometry. Beware that on a dark or on a light background, the outline is only partially visible.

Comment: can you post a sample picture of the disk in the environment you're trying to detect this in?